# Delphi7 created exe on intel galileo windows

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7, galileo

Installed Windows on my Galileo board and that works fine.
I developed a small application i Delphi7 (32 bit exe) that
I have deployed to the Galileo and configured it to start
at boot by configuration in the autorun.cmd file.

start C:\applications\GalileoApp1.exe

The application is formless and contains a TCPserver that echoes back incoming data.

Works fine under windows 7 on my PC.

Does not start automatically or manually on my Galileo.

Has anyone tried something similar and succeeded in executing the application on Galileo?

Are there any limitations on what types of 32bit exe´s that can be executed on the Galileo?

Comment: You need to do some debugging here. Don't be helpless. Inspect the startup of the process and see what is going wrong. Create a trivial do nothing console app that just does `Writeln`. Does that work? Create from  a C++ process by calling `CreateProcess`. Is there an error? If so, what does GetLastError tell you. Debugging, the most underrated of skills.

Comment: Which Windows version did you install on that board?

Comment: It was Windows 8 downloaded from here: https://ms-iot.github.io/content/SetupGalileo.htm. I use Galileo Gen2.

Answer (score 9):

Stock Delphi RTL will not work on that version of Windows. The primary reason is that the Galileo versions of Windows' DLLs are different from the desktop version. This will require a rebuild of the RTL in order to import APis from their new locations. Some APis aren't even supported (such as most of the ones in GDI32 and USER32).

That being said, here at Embarcadero, as a research project I have a version of the Delphi RTL that does run on the Galileo board (I'm looking at the board right now :). I also have a stripped down Delphi conversion of some of the Wiring/Arduino Sketch API. When or even if we release such a thing is purely dependent upon the demand and our intended product direction.

The bottom line is that, yes, it is possible to get a Delphi-built command-line application (no *visual* VCL is supported, or anything that assumes the presence of a GUI). No, it's not a straight-forward, simple process as it requires some significant modifications to the RTL. I would also not recommend using Delphi 7, since the Galileo board doesn't support most of the Ansi versions of the Windows APIs. You will need a Unicode capable version of Delphi to start with.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I really look forward to be able to program applications for the Galileo in Delphi :-). Do you think there will be a different approach programming for Win10 on the RaspberryPi2?

Comment: Please note that I specifically said this was a research project. We don't currently have any specific product plans around the Intel Galileo. As for the Rpi2, we are very keenly interested in that as well. Again, we have nothing to announce or even speculate about other than to say that both devices are on our radar and we're keeping track of that market. I should also point out that the lead for the Microsoft effort on the Galileo and Rpi2 is a former Delphi R&D team member... IOW, he's in my email address book :)